# what is the best way to get latest values per team based on the date in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

i have the following Json object

```
 let my_array = 
  [
  {
    timestamp: '1571967208',
    team: 'team1',
    goals: '2'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1571967150',
    team: 'team2',
    goals: '1'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1571967110',
    team: 'team1',
    goals: '0'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1571967067',
    team: 'team3',
    goals: '4'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1571966896',
    team: 'team1',
    goals: '5'
  },

 ]
```

i want to get the latest from above Json per team based on the timestamp. for example if team 1 latest is goals 2 then new array should only have that likewise for other teams.

expected result like bellow

```
 let my_array = 
  [
   {
    timestamp: '1571967150',
    team: 'team2',
    goals: '1'
   },
   {
    timestamp: '1571967067',
    team: 'team3',
    goals: '4'
   },
   {
   timestamp: '1571966896',
   team: 'team1',
   goals: '5'
   },
 ]
```

since the 5 goals is the latest for team 1 based on the timestamp

Comment: Your question says "i want to get the latest". But, you've rejected the two answers that get you the latest.  I have no idea what else you want. Perhaps you should spend some time and clear up your question and show the actual output you want.

Comment: sorry i've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(a, b) {
  const bandA = a.timestamp.;
  const bandB = b.timestamp;

  let comparison = 0;
  if (bandA > bandB) {
    comparison = 1;
  } else if (bandA < bandB) {
    comparison = -1;
  }
  return comparison;
}

var sortmy_array = my_array.sort(compare);
//to get the latest values 
console.log(sortmy_array[0])
```

Comment: but your solution only return one team. i need for all the teams but the latest

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to distinct the elements based on the team? Then, I would do something like this:

```js
function latest(records) {
  const hash = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    const element = records[i]
    if (
      hash[element.team] == null ||
      hash[element.team].timestamp < element.timestamp
    ) {
      hash[element.team] = element
    }
  }

  return Object.values(hash)
}
```

This function returns below for your data.

```
[
  { timestamp: '1571967208', team: 'team1', goals: '2' },
  { timestamp: '1571967150', team: 'team2', goals: '1' },
  { timestamp: '1571967067', team: 'team3', goals: '4' }
]
```